# TableViewController Class didSelectRowAtIndexPath missing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I'm deploying an `iOS` app using `Swift 3.0` and `10.2 Deployment Target` with `Xcode 8.2.1`. 
I have a problem when I try to find `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function inside the TableViewController Class.

It looks like is missing in this release of Deployment Target.

I want to do a simple conditional segue but I don't no where to put a code like the following:

```
if ((indexPath.row) == 0) {
  performSegue(withIdentifier: "toView1", sender: self)
} else if ( indexPath.row == 2) {
  performSegue(withIdentifier: "toView2", sender: self)
} else {
  performSegue(withIdentifier: "toView3", sender: self)
}
```

I've configured three segues from the `TableViewController` to three different `Views`.

This is an empty `TableViewController Class`:

```
import UIKit

class TableServicesController: UITableViewController {
    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the code of your UITableViewController class ?

Comment: I've edited with new TableViewController Class

Comment: It's an optional delegate method, implement it?

Comment: try copying and pasting this? :   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //your code
    }

Comment: I've posted what was the problem in the answer below. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

No need to set UITableViewDelegate

Comment: The problem was in the storyboard I've deleted the segue and create a new one for all the views, from view controller. The problem was doing the right-click from cell to view instead of TableViewController.

Comment: Like a charm! Thank you very much. I send the previous message without thanking you before. So, thank you!

Comment: Anytime! Can you, please, set the answer as correct so that other users can see the answer and your comments? Some people may have the issue that you have encountered too.

Comment: Why is this answer accepted? It had nothing to do with the problem. If the OP fixed the problem on their own, they should post their own clear answer explaining the solution. But you should not accept an unrelated answer just because the OP posted a relevant comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

add also this method for  didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score -1):

didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not a method of `UITableViewController`. You should implement UITableViewDelegate

Comment: But UITableViewController implements itself UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate, isn't it?